# How can I get Error text element of android app using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I am automating android app. testing. When I do inspect element , there is no base to find error text element. Is there any way to do this?

[image: Popup Error Text]

I am able to access all other elements by id/xpath/classname etc but for error text I am not getting any way to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate `Xpath` by using text as `"//*[contains(text(), 'text')`, you try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Please Enter Username'))).click();
```

Comment: but how can I achieve if I want to do gettext dynamically for that element?

Comment: you cant get it by this way but you define your your expected xpaths by predefined text and then you can use them for assertion or interaction